# GCC Macro with Conditional Expansion?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I am almost certain the answer is 'no'. But I'm stubborn; I would really like to implement this feature, and cycles are important (read: embedded).

**Goal:**

For this embedded application, I have a clock-configuration-sequence which needs to be inlined. All over the place. I would like to do this with a macro.

**Problem**

The sequence of execution for clock-configuration changes with the argument 'f' (new clock frequency).

```
- if (f>10)  do A first
- if (f<=10) do A last
- f is a compile time constant.
```

**Example**

```
#define setup_post10(f) doA(f);  \
                        doB(f);  \
                        doC(f)

#define setup_pre10(f)  doB(f);  \
                        doC(f);  \
                        doA(f)
```

**Question**

How can you encapsulate this with a simple setup(f)? E.g. I would like to:

```
#define set(f)  #if(f>10) \
                    setup_post10(f)  \
                #else                \
                    setup_pre10(f)   \
                #end
```

But it is invalid to use preprocessor directives (e.g. #if) in a macro definition (as I understand it).

Is there a way to do this? For my application every cycle (and byte of flash) is precious; and I am stubborn; I want this level of abstraction in my code.

Thanks!

-Justin

Comment: Is this C or C++?  You have both tagged.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If every cycle is precious, you should be coding in assembly.
 :)

If you trust your C compiler optimizer, then just do this

```
   #define set(f)  if((f)>10) setup_post10(f)  \
            else setup_pre10(f)
```

If `f` is a constant, then the compiler will chose only one of the conditional branches to compile, assuming you have minimal optimization turned on.  For example `set(11)` should translate directly into a call to `setup_post10(11)`

Comment: In any examples, please make sure to protect macro parameters with parens when appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the Boost Preprocessor library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html). It includes a way to do such things - in particular, it has `BOOST_PP_LESS`.

Though if you're only targetting a particular compiler, it'd probably be easier to just use a function instead of a macro, and force it to be inlined. You could then use a simply `if`, and rely on the optimizer to optimize it away for constant arguments. Newer GCC versions even have a way to assert that certain values are compiler-time constants, I think, which would pretty much guarantee that the `if` will never actually be emitted.

Comment: To add onto this, please make sure that the entire function definition is available to the callee at compile time (stick it in a header), and you won't even need to tell the compiler to inline it.  It just will if it makes sense to.

Comment: sometimes you start at a problem too long. letting the compiler do the optimization of the if/else works great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in portability to compilers other than GCC, you can use GCC's 'statement expression' extension to handle this pretty nicely:

```
#define setup_post10(f) ({ doA(f); doB(f); doC(f); 0; })

#define setup_pre10(f)  ({ doB(f); doC(f); doA(f); 0; })

#define set(f) (((f) <= 10) ? setup_pre10(f) : setup_post10(f))
```

If the expression being tested in a conditional operator's controlling expression is a compile time constant, the compiler will only emit code for the the expression that will be executed and elide the code for the branch that will never be executed (maybe not at the `-O0` optimization level).

Comment: You could avoid the GCC-ism by removing the braces and replacing the semicolons with commas in the two setup macros, could you not?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: probably - I didn't want to have to think about things like whether there were implications if any of the `doX()` things were funky macros, so I took what I thought was an easy out.

Comment: I think `#define setup_post10(f) ((doA(f)),(doB(f)),(doC(f)),0)` should be bullet proof. Obviously, subject to the macros such as `doA` generating regular code — no mismatched parentheses in the expansion, etc.  But then there'd be problems regardless if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

I also found using a static-inline function within a header file achieves the same result.

**Example**

```
static inline set(uint8_t f) {

    if(f > 10) {
        doA();
        doB();
        doC();
    } else {
        doB();
        doC();
        doA();
    {
}
```

I found this method to produce more readable code, so I am using it now. Although I must say it breaks one of my golden rules **not to introduce code into header files***!

Justin

*Are there any best practices around the 'code-in-the-header'? I recall a horror story of a project I worked on once where hundreds of line existed with poor structure and formatting within a header file. Thus I am conflicted on using this static-inline method here. Thoughts?